# Least moving-overlapped subset of [1..n] that has the biggest natural density as possible.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-combinatorics

Given a natural number n>1. I'd like to find a set $\phi = \{s_1,s_2, \cdots , s_m \} \subset \{1,2,\cdots , n \} $ with $m > 1$ that minimizes the following quantity:
$$ S_{\phi} = \frac{\max_{k\in\mathbb{N}^*}\frac{\cdot\operatorname{Card}\left[\{s_1 + k, s_2+k, \cdots , s_m+k\} \cap \phi \right]}{m}}{\frac{m}{n}} = \max_{k\in\mathbb{N}^*} \frac{n \cdot\operatorname{Card}\left[\{s_1 + k, s_2+k, \cdots , s_m+k\} \cap \phi \right]}{m^2}$$

Anyone has an idea how to treat this kind of problems?

Comment: @AlexRavsky That's true. What I am interested in is the non trivial case with m greater than 1. I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are searching for minimally symmetric subset of a discrete segment with the group of symmetries consisting of the translations. Such problems and approaches to solve them are known (telling the truth, there were dealt by my professor :-) ), see, for instance, the references ([BVV, §1-2, 5], [BP, Sect. 8], and [B, Sect. 6]).

*References*

[B] T.Banakh, *[Symmetry and Colorings: Some Results and Open Problems, II](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1015)*.

[BVV] T.Banakh, O.Verbitski, Ya.Vorobets, *[Ramsey treatment of symmetry](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v7i1r52/pdf)* // Electronic J. of Combinatorics. 7:1 (2000) R52. – 25p.

[BP] T.Banakh, I.Protasov. *[Symmetry and colorings: some results and open problems](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3356)* // Izv. Gomel Univ. Voprosy Algebry. 2001. Issue 4(17). P.5–16.

Comment: Thanks for the refs. However it seems to me that the results in the refs are very general. Can you plz tell me how the results of your professor can be applied to my problem in detail?

Comment: @corindo I am going to speak with my professor about your question, but at first I’ll try to obtain some results by myself.